# VB.NET SQL Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am relatively new to programming in VB.

Currently, I have a login page that works fine.  After successful login, my user is directed to another form which connects back into an MS Access table and presents data on the screen for them.

I take the logged in user and equal it to a label on the secondary form (after they login).  Basically I want to have a SQL select statement for if the Username column in my access db equals that label, then to pull back the data for that unique user.

It doesn't work.  When I take the where statement out and just do "Select * From Table1" it works fine, but doesn't give me a unique logged in user, which is my goal.

Please help!

Comment: Please note that your code is ***wide open*** to SQL injection attacks.  You should never treat input as *executable SQL code*.  Instead, use parameterized queries to treat input as *values* in your SQL queries.

Comment: Please expand on "doesn't work". Note you appear to have an additional double quote at the end of the `strSQL` definition. What's the data type for the `Username` column?

Comment: unless UserName must be unique AND they cannot change their logon and your app enforces  those rules, a better approach would be to store the UserID as a variable and use that for your data restriction.

Comment: I agree with @ElectricLlama. Even stackoverflow's code highlighter interprets some of the VB code as a string because of that additional double quote. That might be the reason why it works when you "take the where statement out".

Comment: Could the problem be that you are setting `lblUsername.Text` to the value of the logged in user but you are using `Label1.Text` in the query?  What does `Label1.Text` have in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It din't work because of, `misused double quotation`.

May be Something like this

```
lblUsername.Text = login.txtUsername.Text
DbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
DbSource = "Data Source = C:\loginprogram\studentclasslist.mdb"

con.ConnectionString = DbProvider & DbSource

con.Open()

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Username = '" & Label1.Text & "'"
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, con)
da.Fill(ds, "studentclasslist")
con.Close()
```

But this will leads you to **`SQL injection attacks`**. use `parameterized` queries to treat input as values in your SQL queries.

```
lblUsername.Text = login.txtUsername.Text
DbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
DbSource = "Data Source = C:\loginprogram\studentclasslist.mdb"

con.ConnectionString = DbProvider & DbSource

con.Open()

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Username = @UserName"
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, con)
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName",SqlDbType.nvarchar,50).Value = Label1.Text
da.Fill(ds, "studentclasslist")
con.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store your login user id in the session when user logged in successfully.

```
//In your login page
Session["myUser"] = txtUsername.Text
```

Then, you can use the user id from `Session` anywhere in your application.

```
//In your other page.
Dim Cmd As OleDbCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Username=?"
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username",OleDbType.Text,50).Value = Session["myUser"]
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(Cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable()
da.Fill(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent from **SQL injection** as parameters as already been widely suggested. Additionally, you could use `Using` for you connection to dispose right away the connection after it is being used like:

```
Using con As New OleDbConnection(DbProvider & DbSource)
      con.Open()
      strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Username = @UserName"
      da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, con)
      da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName",SqlDbType.nvarchar,50).Value = Label1.Text
      da.Fill(ds, "studentclasslist")
End Using
```

Secondly, you can put the data on a `DataTable`

```
Dim dt as new DataTable 
dt = ds.Tables(0)
```

And assuming that you have one record match you could check if there are records by checking `Records.Count` and if there is save it to a `DataRow` and then `Textboxes`.

```
If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
    Dim dr as DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
    'Field names and Textbox names below are just mine
    txtUserName.Text = dr.Item("Username")
    txtPassword.Text = dr.Item("Password")
    txtUserlevel.Text = dr.Item("UserLevel")
End If
```

So, all in all it would probably look like this:

```
lblUsername.Text = login.txtUsername.Text
DbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
DbSource = "Data Source = C:\loginprogram\studentclasslist.mdb"


Using con As New OleDbConnection(DbProvider & DbSource)

      Dim dt as new DataTable 

      con.Open()
      strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Username = @UserName"
      da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, con)
      da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName",SqlDbType.nvarchar,50).Value = Label1.Text
      da.Fill(ds, "studentclasslist")
      dt = ds.Tables(0)

      If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
         Dim dr as DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
         'Field names and Textbox names below are just mine
         txtUserName.Text = dr.Item("Username")
         txtPassword.Text = dr.Item("Password")
         txtUserlevel.Text = dr.Item("UserLevel")
      End If

End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone. it was the double quote. works now but next is making it sql injection proof which i will learn how to use parameterized queries to prevent against.